# Обработка нажатия кнопки Back в webView

Tags: html, webview, android

Есть две активности. На первой - список ListView, на второй WebView, подгружающий html файлы из raw-ресурсов проекта. Веб-элемент работает под таким простым кодом:

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "raw", "mypackagename"));

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "html", "utf-8", null);
```

В каждом html ресурсе под заголовком есть картинка-ссылка обусловленным размером, ссылается на полный размер самой картинки. Код в html прост, как банный лист:

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/pic1.jpg"><img src="file:///android_asset/pic1.jpg" height="300dp"></a>
```

При выходе из полноразмерной картинки я попадаю на свой список, а не обратно в html файл. Было понятно, что кнопка "BACK" воспринимается layout'ом, а не webView. Почитав документацию от гугла, нашел такой способ:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
    myWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
// If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
// system behavior (probably exit the activity)
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Вроде бы, простейший код, должен работать. Но при проверке оказалось, что возвращаясь из полной картинки, html файл не подгружается обратно, и я попадаю на пустой белый экран, из которого я выхожу уже обратно в список. Быть может, это связано с тем, что у меня много html-файлов, которые в зависимости от условий загружает нужный. Но тут я уже лишь предполагаю, и я в тупике. Что думаете на этот счет вы?